# Keycloak generate pdf of user details

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-admin-client, keycloak-admin-cli

I want to generate a pdf of user details from admin side of keycloak. Does anyone have any idea to achieve this. Once I go inside as an admin, I can see list of users and their details. My goal is to add a button in each user list and generate a pdf with this. How can I do this in admin side.

I saw the keycloak version 23 has admin side build with react. I am finding hard time to achieve this. Adding a button and generate a pdf.

Comment: You can't add a button in Keycloak UI without change Keycloak source, I have an idea, to get User detail information by node.js with master token and then create a PDF file from JSON to PDF using [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)